# Is it possible to use Rails action_text with mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am starting an blog with mongoid and I would like to use trix editor along with all facilities of action_text. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoid cannot be used with ActionText due to its reliance on ActiveStorage, which does not support Mongoid (see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31408).

Requests have been made to remove the dependency on ActiveRecord from ActiveStorage (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/42901) however this is not something Rails core is looking to do.